# Capitalize a string column in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

How to replace a multiple version in easiest way?

Here's my data:

```
No  Device
1   asus
2   Xiaomi
3   xiaomi
4   Asus
5   Samsung
```

I want to make it:

```
No  Device
1   Asus
2   Xiaomi
3   Xiaomi
4   Asus
5   Samsung
```

What I did is:

```
f = {'xiaomi':'Xiaomi', 'asus':'Asus'}
df['Device'] = df['Device'].map(f)
```

But the result is:

```
No  Device
1   Asus
2   NaN
3   Xiaomi
4   NaN
5   NaN
```

Comment: Do you need capitalization?

Comment: If `Asus BEST` then need `Asus best` (capitalize) or `Asus Best` (title)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is not mapping but `replacing` i.e

```
df['Device'] = df['Device'].replace(f)

0       Asus
1     Xiaomi
2     Xiaomi
3       Asus
4    Samsung
Name: Device, dtype: object

​
```

Comment: Ya, to slow, rather not use.

Comment: But its easy :)

Answer (score 6):

Why not just go with `str.title`?

```
df['Device'] = df.Device.str.title()  
df

   No   Device
0   1     Asus
1   2   Xiaomi
2   3   Xiaomi
3   4     Asus
4   5  Samsung
```

There's no need for any mappings or dictionary this way.

Comment: That was clever indeed haha

Answer (score 2):

Add [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) or [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) if need `dictionary` and `map`:

```
df['Device'] = df['Device'].map(f).fillna(df['Device'])
```

Or:

```
df['Device'] = df['Device'].map(f).combine_first(df['Device'])
```

Or use only [`str.capitalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.capitalize.html) if need only first letter uppercase:

```
print (df)
   No     Device
0   1  asus best
1   2     Xiaomi
2   3     xiaomi
3   4       Asus
4   5    Samsung

df['Device'] = df['Device'].str.capitalize()
print (df)
   No     Device
0   1  Asus best
1   2     Xiaomi
2   3     Xiaomi
3   4       Asus
4   5    Samsung
```